# Oracle ODBC 19c driver issues (works in 11g/12c)

Tags: oracle, odbc

Hoping anyone have similar experience.

I have an application that uses the ODBC drivers provided by Oracle. Runs perfectly in 11g and 12c version.

Tried against a Oracle 19c (both server and client 19c version) using also Oracle ODBC 19c. ODBC logs shows errors:

`ConsolidationTe 31c0-1afc    EXIT  SQLGetDiagRecW  with return code -2 (SQL_INVALID_HANDLE)
SQLSMALLINT                  3 <SQL_HANDLE_STMT>
SQLHANDLE           0x00000220BF093FA0
SQLSMALLINT                  1
SQLWCHAR *          0x0000006122EEC240
SQLINTEGER *        0x00000220BEBE270C
SQLWCHAR *          0x0000006122EEC250
SQLSMALLINT                511
SQLSMALLINT *       0x0000006122EEC1F0`

and there some codes that are just plainly hanging:

`AppServ         1338-b1cc ENTER SQLFetchScroll
SQLHSTMT            0x01077150
SQLSMALLINT                  5 <SQL_FETCH_ABSOLUTE>
SQLLEN                     1`

Just for the sake of testing I installed on a different machine, I installed both 12c and 19c clients but using 19c server. When I switch to 12c client driver, everything works as expected but using 19c, same errors as above happened.

Need help on how can I really pinpoint that the 19c driver are the actual issue? Or i need to change something on our 10+ year old codes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you use the `{Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}` Driver. This is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/odbc-driver-for-oracle) for ages and now with Oracle 18/19 the time has come where is does not work anymore.

Use the ODBC driver from Oracle, most likely named `{Oracle in OraClient19c_home1}` or similar. You can download from [Instant Client Downloads for Microsoft Windows 32-bit](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/microsoft-windows-32-downloads.html)

Comment: Hi,

Yes I used the Oracle in OraClient19c_home1... etc... I am very sure as we've been using the version from Oracle in OraClient12c etc before and been working okay. Now that we change drivers to use Oracle in OraClient19c it doesn't anymore...

Comment: Your code/error messages does not indicate which ODBC driver is used. Unless you tell us, I cannot do more than just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issue and watched this video. It shows a different connection string syntax.  I hope it helps you as well.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NAfJzPIaFFQ

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).